# How to count letter based similarity on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, similarity

Here's my first dataframe `df1`

```
Id   Text
1    dFn
2    fiqe
3    raUw
```

Here's my second dataframe `df2`

```
Id   Text
1    yuw
2    dnag
```

Similarity Matrix, columns is `Id` from `df1`, rows is `Id` from `df2`

```
       1      2      3
1      0      0   0.66  
2    0.5      0   0.25
```

Note:

`0` value in (1,1), (2,1) and (3,2) because no letter similar

`0.25` value in (3,1) is because of only 1 letter from `raUw` avaliable in 4 letter `dnag' (1/4 equals 0.25)

`0.5` is counted because of 2 of 4 letter similar

`0.66` is counted because of 2 of 3 words similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one option is to use `set.intersection` in a nested list comprehension:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([[len(set(x.lower()) & set(y.lower())) / len(x) for y in df1['Text'].tolist()] for x in df2['Text'].tolist()])
```

Output:

```
     0    1         2
0  0.0  0.0  0.666667
1  0.5  0.0  0.250000
```